# Ionic 3 when using jquery, navctrl gives error

Tags: jquery, angular, rest, api, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic,

I have used jquery in ionic to call rest api.

When I'm using navCtrl with jQuery following error is coming in chrome console,

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

When using navCtrl without jQuery, navCtrl is working fine.

I want to use jQuery in my project, please help, following is the code I'm using

With jQuery

```
jQuery.post( "http://localhost/ccc/public/api/loginapi", { email: this.email, password: this.password })
        .done(function( data ) {
          localStorage.setItem('id', data.id);
          localStorage.setItem('name', data.name);
          if(data.message == "success") {
              this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);              
          } else {
              this.navCtrl.push(AboutusPage);              
          }
        });
```

Without jQuery

```
this.restProvider.loginUser(JSON.stringify({ email: "aaa@bbb.com", password: "secret" }))
              .then(data => {
                    this.user = data;
                    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);          
              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the arrow operator

```
 jQuery.post( "http://localhost/ccc/public/api/loginapi", { email: this.email, password: this.password })
        .done(( data ) => {  // notice the use of arrow operator here
          localStorage.setItem('id', data.id);
          localStorage.setItem('name', data.name);
          if(data.message == "success") {
              this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);              
          } else {
              this.navCtrl.push(AboutusPage);              
          }
        });
```

Read more about arrow function here: [How is `this` different for arrow function](https://github.com/anirudh-modi/JS-essentials/blob/master/ES2015/Functions/Arrow%20functions.md#how-this-is-different-for-arrow-functions)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it worked. You saved my time.

Comment: glad to help. Do read about arrow functions if you come from jquey background

Comment: Sure Ashfaq.p, I'll look into it.